# SCCM 2007 not installing Forefront Endpoint Protection client

Tags: deployment, sccm, microsoft-forefront-2010

We've recently upgraded from Forefront Endpoint Protection 2007 to 2010 and it now needs SCCM to deploy the clients, so we are using SCCM for the first time and struggling a little bit.

SCCM is fully installed and appears to be working. The clients are XP and have the System Center clients installed on them, but the FEP client are in "pending" - never installing.

If I look at one of the XP Clients and go to "Configuration Manager Properties" from the Control Panel then I can see that the ConfigMgr Site Codes is right and the proper management point path is there.

As this is our first attempt at a SCCM 2007 install we could be missing something really basic. How can I tell why items in "pending" are not installing?

Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that the reporting is not accurately showing what is going on in the network. Some clients HAVE installed FEP, but I've only known that by logging on to those manually. The main problem with the others is that they are unable to properly uninstall Symantec Antivirus first even though FEP is supposed to do it. Manually uninstalling SAV allows FEP to later install, but the reporting part of the server shows only one "deployed" even though there have been a few installed for at least four days. I guess this is now a question regarding SCCM reporting.

Comment: Many packages don't report status at all until the very end with either a success or failure. It could be that the install is waiting for something else to happen, could be a reboot, could be a pre-req install, could be a pre-req uninstall. Either way the package has started but hasn't actually finished.

Comment: Thanks, these machines have been rebooted many times now though and according to Microsoft they think it may be a WMI problem on the clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this particular problem turned out to be a corruption in the BITS service in IIS. Looking through the whole things as soon as you hit the BITS box an error popped up. The solution was to remove the BITS feature and then reinstall it. All worked fine after that - once we pushed out the deployment again.
Cheers for the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's an overview of deploying the client [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/clientsecurity/archive/2010/08/31/how-to-deploy-forefront-endpoint-protection-beta-2010-clients-using-configuration-manager.aspx)

A couple of things to check for any software distribution troubleshooting:

- Look at the c:\windows\system32\ccm\logs\execmgr.log on the client. This is the log that tracks package installs
- Are the clients actually in a collection to receive the package?
- Is the advertisement mandatory?  If you just set a start date with no mandatory installation date, the package will not run

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I've got a support case open with Microsoft regarding this at the moment and I'll add a comment to the original post to update it. I did not know about the mandatory setting though, so that will be very useful.